# Couchbase nodejs 4.1.0 sdk unzipped size causing an issue for lambda layers

Tags: node.js, sdk, couchbase

We have our existing lambda layers using the CB nodejs 3.2.3 sdk which is being used in the lambda functions/handlers and the sdk when unzipped used to have a size of 13mb thus when used along with the functions would not cross total size of around 20mb

But with using the latest nodejs 4.1.0 sdk the unzipped file size of the layer itself is now around 245+mb thus the function/handler size now crossing the total limit of "250mb"

- is there a way to reduce the size of the sdk , there seems to be folder named `couchbase-cxx-client` , `couchbase-transactions-cxx` under deps ( do we really need them for basic usage ? )

did try to remove the `couchbase-cxx-client` which reduces the size my 40mb and it seems to work well as expected ( is that acceptable to remove those ? )
also we dont want to switch to lambda containers as of yet to support 250mb+ size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got this solution from the forum , that we can delete the entire dep,src folder if the installation is already done. [ref](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-nodejs-4-1-0-sdk-unzipped-size-causing-an-issue-for-lambda-layers/34766/2)